# Bot work in local but not in azure

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint, botframework, csom

I'm working on a chat bot that help users of a SharePoint on premise network to upload a file. The bot works on local but returns code 500 when tested in Azure.

I'm using Csom library to navigate in the site tree and the SharePoint _api to get all site collections. I have done some test and I don't think that is the Csom that causes this bug, but rather it is the NetworkCredential that doesn't work in Azure.

So can I use credential in Azure ?

I know that the problem comes from this function

```
public void GetAllSiteCollections(string url)
    {

        HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url + "/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:sts_site'&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=100");

        endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
        endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(Login, Mdp, DomaineUser);
        endpointRequest.Credentials = cred;
        HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();

        WebResponse webResponse = endpointRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
        string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

        JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(response);

        for (int ind = 0; ind < jobj["d"]["query"]["PrimaryQueryResult"]["RelevantResults"]["Table"]["Rows"]["results"].Count(); ind++)
        {

            string urlCollection = jobj["d"]["query"]["PrimaryQueryResult"]["RelevantResults"]["Table"]["Rows"]["results"][ind]["Cells"]["results"][6]["Value"].ToString();
            string nomCollection = jobj["d"]["query"]["PrimaryQueryResult"]["RelevantResults"]["Table"]["Rows"]["results"][ind]["Cells"]["results"][3]["Value"].ToString();
            if (urlCollection.Contains("myLocalDomain/sites/") == true)
            {
                string[] split = urlCollection.Split('/');
                ClientCtx = new ClientContext(Domaine + "/sites/" + split[4]);
                using (ClientCtx = new ClientContext(ClientCtx.Url))
                {
                    ClientCtx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Login, Mdp, DomaineUser);
                    Web rootWeb = ClientCtx.Site.RootWeb;
                    ClientCtx.Load(rootWeb);

                    BasePermissions bp = new BasePermissions();
                    bp.Set(PermissionKind.AddListItems);

                    ClientResult<bool> viewListItems = rootWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions(bp);


                    ClientCtx.ExecuteQuery();
                    if (viewListItems.Value)
                    {
                        ListDesSiteCollections.Add(nomCollection, split[4]);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        responseReader.Close();

    }
```

When I check the logs at http://botName.azurewebsites.net/api/messages I get the response "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'"

Comment: Quick question: why don't you use Graph API to query Sharepoint?

Comment: Because I have seen on a other post that it's impossible to use Graph API to get all site collections

Comment: the responseyou get when navigating your browser to your bots endpoint is the correct response.  What channel(s) are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the delay i can't access to my work station during the week end, I use web chat and teams channels